# "Welcome user" on the same page without textboxes

Tags: php

I am very new at php and I'm trying to create a login div on the right side bar. Well it's seems to work but when I login it shows me:

```
user name [     textbox         ]
password  [     textbox         ]
          [     login button    ]


welcome new2
```

Obviously, I'm not intrested of showing the textboxing and the login button because the user is already login.

Here is the code of the home page (templat.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet2.css" />
    </head>
    <body dir="rtl">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation" dir="rtl">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="indexForum.php">topics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">on us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!--
            <div id="content_area">
                <?php
                //echo $content; ?>

            </div>
            -->
            <div id="sidebar">

    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <center><h2>Login Form</h2></center>
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                            <center>
                <img src="images/avatar.png" width='60' height='60' alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                            </center>
            </div>
        <form action="Template.php" method="post">
            <div class="inner_container">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                                <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                                <br/>
                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                                <br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                                <br/>
                <button class="login_button" name="login" 
           type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
             if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {


                $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
                $password=md5($password); //Remember we hashed password before storing last time


                $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

                $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);  
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($num==1)
                {
                    $_SESSION['message']="You are now Loggged In";
                    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
                 ?>   
                  <div id="main-wrapper">
        <center><h3>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h3></center>

        <form action="Template.php" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar"  width='60' height='60' class="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="inner_container">
                <button class="logout_button" type="submit">Log Out</button>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



                 <?php   
                }
               else
               {
                  $_SESSION['message']="Username and Password combiation incorrect";
                }
            }
            ?>

                </br>
            </div>

            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>aaa</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

update : logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
$_SESSION['message']="You are now logged out";
header("Location:login.php");
?>
```

Comment: you can check with session is user logged in redirect to another page

Comment: Have different pages for login and inner content.

Comment: you need to put an if condition there. Like if (empty($_SESSION)) show login div else show welcome user

Comment: @justinas I did that and use the function header and still it shows me the textbox's. Any help with correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user is already logged in. You can check if `$_SESSION['username']` is empty or not.

Update your login form like that:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>

<form action="Template.php" method="post">
        <div class="inner_container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
            <br/>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
            <br/>
            <button class="login_button" name="login"
                    type="submit">Login
            </button>
        </div>
</form>

<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: zadrazil , are you sure? because right now it doesn't show me the text box at all even when I loged out.

Comment: see my comment.

Comment: @Jordan1200 it depend on what you are doing with $_SESSION after logout. This work only if you fully unset $_SESSION['username']. Try if(empty($_SESSION['username'])), you need to unset $_SESSION['username'] or set it to empty.

Comment: where to unset the session?

Comment: Show me the part of code, where do you handling users logout.